# LTC timecode Bi-Phase Mark Phase Correction

Tags: timecodes

I am writing a program to generate timecode.
I don't understand in which case I need to set the parity bit. That for 25FPS it is 59 bits and for 24/30FPS it is 27 bits I understand.

Wikipedia says

> "Polarity correction bit" (bit 59 at 25 frame/s, bit 27 at other
> rates): this bit is chosen to provide an even number of 0 bits in the
> whole frame, including the sync code. (Since the frame is an even
> number of bits long, this implies an even number of 1 bits, and is
> thus an even parity bit. Since the sync code includes an odd number of
> 1 bits, it is an odd parity bit over the data.) This keeps the phase
> of each frame consistent, so it always starts with a rising edge at
> the beginning of bit 0.

I need to count the number of zeros and ones in an 80 bit parcel and depending on the number set the bit? I've tried to figure it out, but I can't figure it out.